# Как при повторном клике сдвигать в исходное положение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var htt = $('.kat-body').height();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.kat-title').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('kat-title-open');
    $('.kat-body').toggleClass('kat-body-open');
    $('#sidebar').css('margin-top', htt);
  });
});
```

По клику на `.kat-title` `#sidebar` сдвигается вниз, путём увеличения `margin-top` на n-ое количество пикселей (на высоту `.kat-body`). Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при повторном клике `#sidebar` сдвигался наверх в исходное положение.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, выложите HTML

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь это то, что нужно :)

```js
const foo = document.querySelector(".foo");
const baz = document.querySelector(".baz");
const height = foo.offsetHeight;

foo.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!foo.classList.contains("foo_open")) {
    foo.classList.add("foo_open");
    baz.style.marginTop = height + "px";
  } else {
    foo.classList.remove("foo_open");
    baz.style.marginTop = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.foo,
.baz {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.baz {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="baz"></div>
```